# Two Tails Interlinked

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

> > **Riddle Me This:**
>
> *I gallop in pairs underneath all the waves.*
>
> *I hope that my children aren't what he depraves.*
>
> *I'm upright, not forward like most of my friends.*
>
> *I thank my consumption as it never ends.*
>
> *We dance for as long as your pillow bears weight.*
>
> *It's colour, not matter, in changing of state.*
>
> *Inept as I am since without I can tire,*
>
> *Though guess what I am to fulfil your desire.*

My previous riddles were longer, thus describing the subject in more detail and making the riddle potentially straightforward. I have made it shorter now $(8$ lines instead of $10)$ and I have tried making the rhyming a little bit juicier.

I also will not be putting hints until tomorrow if this riddle is not answered (or answered incorrectly), and I also assume your desire is to answer this riddle :)

Hope you enjoy!

---

**Edit:**

The last line 
 `Guess what I am to fulfil your desire` 
 is part of the riddle (and not just a fancy way to finish it off). 
 
 
 
 Added the word "though" to the last line, as it makes better-matching syllables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you're a

> Sea horse (hippocamp)

Two Tails Interlinked

> During the courtship process (dance), the male and female often interlink their tales.

I gallop in pairs underneath all the waves.

> A horse gallops, sea-horses gallop under the sea. In pairs because some species form monogam couples; or because of the famous breeding process during wihch they're in pairs.

I hope that my children aren't what he depraves.

> Probably related to the fact that male sea-horses give birth, not the females.

I'm upright, not forward like most of my friends.

> Sea horses are upright, opposite to common fishes.

I thank my consumption as it never ends.

> It eats by absorbing ocean water, which is practically endless.

We dance for as long as your pillow bears weight.

> Refers to the mating dance, don't know about the pillow though.

It's colour, not matter, in changing of state.

> They sometimes change color during the courtship process

Inept as I am since without I can tire.

> I have no clue.

Guess what I am to fulfil your desire.

> There seems to be something about a "seahorse wish" in English, probably some superstition involving seahorses giving birth and wishes, although I don't know what it is...

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Jryy qbar, lbh tbg vg! Sbe gur sbhegu evqqyr-yvar, V zrnag gung frnubefrf pna arire fgbc rngvat sbe ybat crevbqf bs gvzr (orpnhfr gurve qvtrfgvir flfgrz vf cbbe---gurl unir ab fgbznpu!) ohg lbhe nafjre vf irel zhpu npprcgnoyr. Sbe gur svsgu evqqyr-yvar, ol "cvyybjf ornevat jrvtug" V zrnag "ubj ybat lbh erfg lbhe urnq; v.r., ubj ybat lbh fyrrc" juvpu vf nobhg rvtug ubhef, nyfb ubj ybat frnubefrf qnapr sbe. Sbe gur friragu evqqyr-yvar, jvgubhg sbbq, frnubefrf trg rkunhfgrq; gurl gver. Tbbq wbo, gubhtu!$]$

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Naq nyfb, lbh jbhyq unir gb or yhpxl gb "thrff" jung gur nafjre vf. Va fbzr phygherf, frnubefrf ercerfrag zntvp naq yhpx.$]$ $\;$ :)

Comment: If you don't know [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$Uryyb!$]$ means to copy-and-paste the phrase **Uryyb!** in the upper box of the website **Rot13** to view a secret coded message! (In this case, the message is *Hello!*). Also, go [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/change+of+state) to explain the added reference in my sixth line.

Comment: [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)[Nz V gur bayl bar jub svaq gur EBG13 zrffntrf naablvat? fher, jr arrq n zrpunavfz gb nibvq fcbvyref, ohg nyybj fcbvyre gntf va gur pbzzragf frrz n zhpu orggre fbyhgvba guna jevgvat nyy bhe pbzzragf ba n tvoorevfu ebbg flfgrz jvgu znaqngbel pbcl/cnfgr ba rkgreany jrofvgr]

Comment: @Kepotx [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)[NSNVX, gung srngher pnaabg or vzcyrzragrq va n fvatyr Fgnpx Rkpunatr fvgr; vg erdhverf fbzr zbqvsvpngvba npebff gur ragver Fgnpx Rkpunatr argjbex. Gehfg zr, vg'f abg nf fvzcyr nf "pbclvat naq cnfgvat gur fcbvyre pbqr hfrq sbe cbfgf."]

Comment: @user477343 comments are ideally about improving answers, not just adding some extra thoughts you wanted to share; they're intended to be impermanent and not, well, chat-like (we have chat for that). Oftentimes it's possible to give feedback on an answer without direct spoilers; but sometimes it's rot13 or nothing. But use it sparingly and only when needed. See also  [How do we deal with coded comments?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4651) - the end, in particular. If you use the format  rot13(some text) instead of square brackets, the mentioned addon makes decoding much simpler.

Comment: (@Kepotx see above)

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ okay, thank you for that. I usually use square brackets (because sometimes I may use brackets in my rot13 comment, so I use the square brackets to differentiate). Apologies for not seeing your comment earlier...